# Access data from my own API within rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have a rails app that has an API laid on top of it which other apps are able to call. I am interested in trying to get data from my own api to display on a page in the same rails app, without using a gem.

How could I do that?

Comment: Are you using any gem to generate the output, such as rabl or ActiveModel::Serializers? Or just doing a straight `render json: results`?

Comment: the latter, `render json: results`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it all you need to do is this

```
require 'open-uri'
payload = open('https://people.com/api/v2/survey/search?value=test') #This is an instance of Tempfile, so you can call JSON.parse(payload) or view the payload as below
open('https://people.com/api/v2/survey/search?value=test').read
```

I do believe that this might not be the right architectural decision, but I leave that to you to decide

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the right approach would be to abstract whatever logic you're using to generate your API response to a level where both API and non-API controllers could use it. But, if you really wanted to, you could invoke the API's controller action from another controller. It's pretty hacky though.

Comment: Yea - That's an idea. When you say it's pretty hacky, I agree, but do you see any negative implications of doing it that way, outside of potentially writing more code than is necessary?

Comment: Instead of calling one controller from another, create a new intermediate object that they can both call. This has the added benefit of thinning logic from your controllers (which is good).